# Android Phonegap Get Locale

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm trying to get locslization details of the phone. But it returns an error. Following is the code I hae used, which is the sample of PhoneGap API document (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html).

```
 function checkLocale() {
  navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
    function (locale) {alert('locale: ' + locale.value + '\n');},
    function () {alert('Error getting locale\n');}
  );
}
```

Your help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you give permissions for Android ? in app/res/xml/config.xml ?

Comment: Hi, I'm new to android. Would be grateful if you are able to tell me the specific permission that need to be set.

Comment: I don't know about Android, but following the documentation of cordova, I imagine that you have to give permissions ... I answered you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read documentation of your link, and it says that it's needed to give permissions in android:

Permissions

Android

In **app/res/xml/config.xml**

```
<plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization" />
```

Hope that it helps you.
Regards, Daniel

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response. Isn't it the AndroidManifest.xml where permissions should be defined? And also are there any tag as <plugin>. Thanks.

Comment: Add <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization" /> literally to the config.xml ... try in this file, if not, it will be in AndroidManifest. Good luck!

Comment: Hi,I did not find a config.xml. So I put it to the AndroidManifest.xml. It gives errors. I put it as follows "<permission   > <plugin  name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization" /> </permission>". Any advice's?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding permission in phonegap config.xml.

```
    <access origin="*"/> <!-- allow all pages -->
    <!--
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->

    <!-- Globalization plugin configuration-->
    <feature name="Globalization">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.globalization.Globalization" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```